# how can i make the cards align from left to right in bootstrap? right now its aligned from top to bottom

Tags: alignment, bootstrap-5, card

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y97jP.jpg)
I need it to look like the above image that ive attached. `
The code below is my code right now. A little advice,suggestions, solutions will surely help me. Thanks.

```
 <div class="card" style="width: 16.5rem">
      <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
      <div class="card-body">
        <center>
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
            bulk of the card's content.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card" style="width: 16.5rem">
      <div class="card-body">
        <center>
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
          <p class="card-text">
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
            bulk of the card's content.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card" style="width: 16.5rem">
      <div class="card-body">
        <center>
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
          <p class="card-text">
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
            bulk of the card's content.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card" style="width: 16.5rem">
      <div class="card-body">
        <center>
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
          <p class="card-text">
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
            bulk of the card's content.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
```

`

I have tried using div class float left bu its not working. Im just starting to learn bootstrap and Ill be more than happy if you all going to give me tips.

Comment: if you look here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/card/
they have examples of cards that align horizontaily

Comment: if you learn about Bootstrap grid, then using rows and col's solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

> Add Row and Col divs

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col">
    <div class="card" style="width: 16.5rem">
  <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
  <div class="card-body">
    <center>
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
        Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
        bulk of the card's content.
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
 </div>

<div class="col">
  <div class="card" style="width: 16.5rem">
  <div class="card-body">
    <center>
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
      <p class="card-text">
        Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
        bulk of the card's content.
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <div class="card" style="width: 16.5rem">
  <div class="card-body">
    <center>
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
      <p class="card-text">
        Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
        bulk of the card's content.
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
</div> 


<div class="col">
  <div class="card" style="width: 16.5rem">
  <div class="card-body">
    <center>
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
      <p class="card-text">
        Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
        bulk of the card's content.
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

  
  
</div>
```

Comment: it works, thanks a lot,  but how can I manipulate the space per card? I need them to be a little bit closer with each other

Comment: You are able to change the col size, for example col-8 or col-4. As far as I know, there isn't a way to change the space between the cards. You can read more here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/